# How does an Indexer work with a FilteredElementCollector?

Tags: ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am reading data in from CSV text file where each line in the file is a distinct record. In that record is the name of a text style which I need to convert to the elementID of a TextNoteType.

I have a FilteredElementCollector to get a list of all text styles (as shown below) but what I need to do is pull an elementID from that based on the style name. I would rather not use a loop for that but something like a Python dictionary. For example: A = StyleList["stylename"]

Looking at this code snippet from Revit Python Shell:

```
ListOfTextStyles = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass (TextNoteType)
a = ListOfTextStyles.ToElements()
a.Item
```

When I get to the point of typing "a.item" I see the following which suggests an indexer might be available to do what I want but I do not quite understand how...

[image: indexer image]

Is it possible to do something like: a(property = "type name")["style name"] to get a TextNoteStyle element?

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [definition of the FilteredElementCollector class](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/263cf06b-98be-6f91-c4da-fb47d01688f3.htm). It is a generic collection of `Element`. So, an automatic indexer is available, and `Item` presumably returns an `Element`. If the current element is a `TextNoteStyle`, you can cast it to such and use its methods.

Sorry, I missed the (unnecessary) call to `ToElements`. Similar arguments apply there; it returns a generic `List` of `Element`.

However, there is mostly no need for the `ToElements` method. You can just leave it away. Doing so may even [save memory and improve performance](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-distinguish-redundant-rooms.html#2).

This question was also raised and discussed in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [Indexer and FilteredElementCollector](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/indexer-and-filteredelementcollector/m-p/12309984).

Comment: Hmm...some interesting points.

Comment: Hmm...Some interesting points. 

As a generic collection, a test shows that this works (using previously posted code):

'for item in ListOfTextStyles:
   print item
'
however this does not: 'print ListOfTextStyles[0]' It returns error "object is not subscriptable'

On the other hand, you pointed out that ToElements() returns a generic list. So, with the previously posted code, 'print a[0]' works fine.

Comment: Sorry for mish-mash on the previous comment. I have not got the hang of how to format these comments yet.

Comment: In any case, what I am really after is the ability to pull out an element from the collection, or the list, using the text style name. I know I can step thru the collection using a FOR loop but I would rather not. I guess RPTHOMAS108 over on Revit API forum, had the correct answer - no, it is not possible.

Comment: The collector is enumerable, so you get the elements one at a time one after the other. The advantage of that is that no memory or time overhead is required. The disadvantage is that you cannot pull out an arbitrary element, specified by index. ToElements pulls out all the elements and puts them into a list. This costs time and memory. In a large BIM, it can be a lot of time and a lot of memory, e.g., tens of thousands of elements. I recommend avoiding that if you can, unless you never work with a large BIM.